# Playing YouTube video in an Android application

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, youtube-api

I have been trying to get a link to the video of YouTube accessed with YouTube data API.
I want to play the video in my own application but but haven't found a way yet. So far I have tried using WebView, without success. WebView shows the whole page, instead of showing just video.

Comment: If you got Video URL then you can easily play video using VideoView.

Comment: The url I am talking about is the web url not the video url.

Comment: Check out [this Google 2012 IO session](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/120/), it should answer all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:VIDEO_ID"));
startActivity(i);
```

Here is how you get video id,

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
String vid = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
```

And of course you can use whole url.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxLG2wtE7TM")));
```

[Here](http://www.keyeslabs.com/joomla/blogs/i-think-im-becoming-an-android/51-polish-your-app-free-embeddable-android-youtube-activity) is a great article on this.

Comment: The link you specified, I have already tried the code and it always show "Sorry, this video cannot be played".

Comment: No I am trying it on Galaxy Note ICS model.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this and is more a workaround than a proper solution, but you say you tried playing with a webview. I believe it is not to hard to create an empty html page with only a youtube video embedded. [tuturial](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/article.php/3480061/How-To-Add-a-YouTube-Video-to-Your-Web-Site.htm)

Now you can put this html file in your assets or somewhere else and put that in your webview, now you have a webview that only displays a youtube video i guess.